# open particular slide of powerpoint presentation from access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently using the following code in Access VBA to open a presentation when the path is stored in a variable "link".

```
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application

Set pptApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(link)
```

It works fine, but I actually need the Slide 3 of the presentation to open. Is there any way I can program the Slide Number to open automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
pptPres.Slides(3).Select()
```